# Android: Customcan GridView not work well when it set both setOnItemClickListener() and setOnItemLongClickListener() method

Tags: android, gridview

there is a custom gridView:

```
public class MyGridView extends GridView {

    public MyGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }
    public MyGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }
    public MyGridView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

    }
}
```

then set `setOnItemClickListener()` and `setOnItemLongClickListener()` method for this gridView, in  `onItemLongClick()` I return `true` . befor invoke `setOnItemLongClickListener()` method the `setOnItemClickListener()` work very well,but after invoke `setOnItemLongClickListener()` method once time ,both `setOnItemClickListener()` and `setOnItemLongClickListener()` can not work. No matter what the operation is no response

anybody can help me? thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you set the following listeners in your Fragment or Activity after you instantiate the gridview, you should be able to see the log statements in LogCat when you click or long-click on an item in your gridview.   If you have done this, I'd first try the code with a generic gridview (not the custom one) and make sure that works.  That also means your adapter needs to be setup correctly so that items are populated in the gridview.   These listeners won't do anything if there are no items in the gridview.

If this doesn't solve it, then I'd suggest posting your Fragment/Activity code with the Adapter code and possibly also the XML you are using for your Fragment/Activity layout so we can see where else the problem might be.

I've tested the below code with one of my gridviews and it works just fine.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    MyGridView gridView = (MyGridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    ...

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Log.v(TAG,"CLICK: ItemClick");              
        }           
    });

    gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Log.v(TAG,"CLICK: LongClick");
            return false;
        }           
    });
```

Comment: it do not work!everything is the standard,just only the gridview is custom

Comment: Did you test your code with a generic gridview and verify that everything works?

Comment: Regarding, your custom gridview, what are you trying to accomplish?   Normally the size you pass into 'makeMeasureSpec' should be related to whatever you are laying out. For example, the height of the display area you want to fill.  Setting it to Integer.MAX_VALUE isn't likely to accomplish much because no screen is that size anyway. Custom gridviews are generally not needed and are pretty tricky to get right in the odd cases that you do need to customize them. Perhaps there is another way to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

MyGridView gridView = (MyGridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.gridview);

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        Log.v(TAG,"CLICK: ItemClick");              
    }           
});

gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        Log.v(TAG,"CLICK: LongClick");
        return true;
    }           
});
```